# Double claw on single toe?

Tags: cats, grooming

It was time to trim my cat's murder claws when I noticed something odd; a smaller claw was under her regular claw.

[image: Photo of cat's claw with a second claw beneath the main]

I had not noticed it before and I am wondering if this is a cause for concern. She lets me trim her nails and touch her paws without fussing. She doesn't seem to be exhibiting any pain and she walks around without difficulty.

Is this normal or should I be taking her to the vet?

Comment: is this the hind paw or the front paw?the number of claws a cat have is four claws on each of the hind paws and five on each of the front paws(some breeds have more toes).more pictures of the paws might be helpful in solving this.you should take your cat to the vet but not because of the claw,keeping an eye on the health of your cat will help your cat having a long good life.

Comment: Is your cat polydactyl by any chance? (Does she have more than 5 toes?)

Comment: @trondhansen This is on her front right paw and she does have only five on the front paws.

Comment: @SerenaT No, she is not polydactyl.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is most likely not an entire claw but just one single old layer of her regular claw that didn't separate completely.

Cats claws consist of many layers, like an onion. The newest layer grows from the toe bone on the inside of the claw. The oldest layer is the outermost one and after some time it separates from the rest of the claw and falls off, revealing a fresh, murder-sharp tip underneath. You may have noticed small and thin fragments of cat claws around her scratching post.

Often times the oldest layer doesn't separate in one piece and often the individual pieces don't separate at the same time. What you see in the picture is probably just the oldest layer of the backside of the claw that started separating from the tip but is still attached at the toe. If you look again now, the piece may have already fallen off. If it's still attached, you could try jently poking it or running your fingernails along the backside of her claw. You'll probably notice that this piece is more flexible than her claw.

Comment: After finally getting a chance to trim her claws, I did notice that it was no longer there so it must have fallen off. Thank you.

Comment: @agarza one can see air inside the largest claw in your picture,sometimes a cat shed multiple layers of a claw it can look like the entire claw at first but it is not :)